# Booting an Hibernate Reactive serviceregistry on a non-reactive RecordedState

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, quarkus, reactive, quarkus-panache

I'm trying to migrate to the Quarkus Hibernate Reactive dependencies, so I commented out the old ones and added the new reactive dependencies:

```
//implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-agroal'

//implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-jdbc-postgresql'
//implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm'
//implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache'

implementation "io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-envers"
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-validator'

        
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-reactive'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-reactive-panache'
implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-reactive-pg-client'
```

But I'm getting this error during the startup:

```
2022-01-25 09:10:46,203 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.dev.appstate.ApplicationStateNotification.waitForApplicationStart(ApplicationStateNotification.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl.runMainClass(StartupActionImpl.java:122)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:456)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:149)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:105)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
    at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:104)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:120)
    at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig.startAll(JPAConfig.java:72)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig_Subclass.startAll$$superforward1(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig_Subclass$$function$$5.apply(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:54)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.proceed(InvocationInterceptor.java:62)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor.monitor(InvocationInterceptor.java:51)
    at io.quarkus.arc.runtime.devconsole.InvocationInterceptor_Bean.intercept(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InterceptorInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.perform(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:41)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.InvocationContexts.performAroundInvoke(InvocationContexts.java:32)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig_Subclass.startAll(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.HibernateOrmRecorder.startAllPersistenceUnits(HibernateOrmRecorder.java:97)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits1868654632.deploy_0(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.HibernateOrmProcessor$startPersistenceUnits1868654632.deploy(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.java:93)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$LazyPersistenceUnit.get(JPAConfig.java:149)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.JPAConfig$1.run(JPAConfig.java:58)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Booting an Hibernate Reactive serviceregistry on a non-reactive RecordedState!
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.boot.registry.PreconfiguredReactiveServiceRegistryBuilder.checkIsReactive(PreconfiguredReactiveServiceRegistryBuilder.java:77)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.boot.registry.PreconfiguredReactiveServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(PreconfiguredReactiveServiceRegistryBuilder.java:67)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.rewireMetadataAndExtractServiceRegistry(FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.java:177)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.java:156)
    at io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.runtime.FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernateReactivePersistenceProvider.java:82)
    ... 5 more
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem, but it fixed just adding this in configuration :

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc=false
```

this config for ignore the jdbc driver.